# How do you edit mongo.conf file in bash (if it is running inside the container in local environment)

Tags: database, docker, devops, percona

URL: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/23/deploy-mongodb-replica-set-with-transport-encryption-part-2/

if the percona mongodb setup is running in the local machine with different port ids, how do you edit the file mongod.conf which will be in bash state.

Comment: What do you mean with "bash state"? But as a general answer: you could "mount" the config files as a module as a volume like it is described in https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo under "Using a custom MongoDB configuration file
". This is perfectly fine for local development and trying things out. Of course if you then want to switch to production you might want to build a custom image for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have considered the next options to approach:

1. Build your own image inherits from percona/official image:

   - Write [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) file, `COPY` needed config file and [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) new image
   - Copy config file into running container and [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to the new image
2. [Mount volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) contains config file from local disk into a running container.

Comment: command :  # docker run -d -p 27019:27017 --restart always --name psmb -v /mongodb/database/:/etc/ -d 7c3f204b6d15 --config /etc/mongod.conf 
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>

Comment: Above is the command, I used to create a container, but it creates in exited state, checked docker logs but not able to reach the container configuration file to make changes. Any suggestion.....!

Comment: Please read the documentation. I gave you all the needed links...